# buffer() built-in function in python3.4 error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a code that basically creates a database by fetching location from a "where.data" file and then concatenating it properly with a base_url to hit the googlemaps api . The initial code was written in python 2.7 and I'm having an error with a particular line of code 
`

```
fh = open("where.data")
count = 0
for line in fh:
    if count > 200 : break
    address = line.strip()
    print ('')
    cur.execute("SELECT geodata FROM Locations WHERE address=?",repr(memoryview(buffer(address))), ))

    try:
        data = cur.fetchone()[0]
        print ("Found in database ",address)
        continue
    except:
        pass
```

where the code initially just used `(buffer(address),)`. The error that it's showing is:[image]

Comment: have you tried just removing `buffer`?

Comment: Could you elaborate? i have used `repr(memoryview(address))` in my code above(not exactly though, i used `repr(memoryview(buffer(address)))`)...when i use `repr(memoryview(address))`..it says "string object doesn't have buffer interface"

Comment: @JaredGoguen I think `(repr(memoryview(bytes(address,'utf-8')))` solved it but not quite sure yet

Comment: Wait, won't that code just produce something like `'<memory at 0x02110940>'`? Are you sure you don't just want the raw string `address`?

Comment: @JaredGoguen it doesn't work...i do need a string...can't find a way out